# Is it possible to put a button on either side of text?

Tags: html, css, button

I want to have a button on one side of the page, text, and then another button on the right of the text. I know I can create separate divs but that gets messy. Is there an easier, cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too simple, must be a trap

http://jsfiddle.net/ESDjH/ first try.

http://jsfiddle.net/XwTZR/ second edition.

html:

```
<p>
    <button class="pull-left">Button 1</button>put text here<button class="pull-right">Button 2</button>
</p>
```

css:

```
p {text-align:center;
    width:333px; /* some width based on button + text + button width */
    margin:auto; /* will center your P */
}
.pull-left{float:left}
.pull-right{float:right}
```

Comment: it's not that easy. the point was to have the buttons on either side of the text. the minute the text gets too long, the buttons are out of place again.

Comment: Well, width:333px; **some width based on button + text + button width ** and margin:auto; ** will center your P **  will set you up.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
<p><button>Button 1</button>asd<button>Button 2</button></p>
```

what you want? Does this seems too messy to you?
You can always use languages that compiles to HTML like [Haml](http://haml.info/) or [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)

Comment: not exactly....I need it to be horizontal. so the layout should look like---button-----text-----button-----

Comment: I need, "Please put text here" in the middle of the buttons. I just don't know how how to do that without using divs. http://jsfiddle.net/W6CSy/

Comment: did you meant "<p><button>Button 1</button>Please put text here<button>Button 2</button></p>" ?